# openpyxl pivot table and pandas pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, openpyxl

How create pivot table using openxlpy library which is equivalent to the following pandas pivot table function?

```
import pandas as pd 

import numpy as np 


# creating a dataframe 

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['John', 'Boby', 'Mina', 'Peter', 'Nicky'], 

      'B': ['Masters', 'Graduate', 'Graduate', 'Masters', 'Graduate'], 

      'C': [27, 23, 21, 23, 24]}) 

table = pd.pivot_table(df, values ='A', index =['B', 'C'], 
                         columns =['B'], aggfunc = np.sum)
```

Comment: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pivot.html

Comment: I already seen this. They are not mentioned equivalent function of this.

Comment: Have you attempted any code in openpyxl? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for us to aid you. Please review [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for a better response.

Comment: I wrote code into pandas I want to do same thing by using openpyxl. In documentation they not mentioned clearly and the pivote example is also not very usefilul which they given in documentation of openpyxl. The pandas code I am updated. Thank you for responce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this reach your desired result?

```py
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

# creating a dataframe 

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['John', 'Boby', 'Mina', 'Peter', 'Nicky'], 

      'B': ['Masters', 'Graduate', 'Graduate', 'Masters', 'Graduate'], 

      'C': [27, 23, 21, 23, 24]}) 

table = pd.pivot_table(df, values ='A', index =['B', 'C'], 
                         columns =['B'], aggfunc = np.sum)

table.to_excel("filename.xlsx")
```

**Outputs**

[image: Excel Output]

Comment: yes. I want to implement the same without using pandas. I want to implement it using openpyxl pivot

Comment: I understand now, I will try to help